# What's the largest possible particle/atom that can experience quantum tunneling?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-tunneling

Quantum tunneling occurs when the energy state of a particle gets sufficiently high. Does this mean that particles traveling at relativistic speeds are more likely to experience this phenomena?

Is it possible for an atom the size of lead (say isotope Pb-207) to quantum tunnel through a very thin sheet?